# CASTing a datetime to string if null value - keeping original datetime formatting

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, isnull

I have the following part of my query:

```
ISNULL(cast(fd.decision_date as varchar(20)), 'PENDING') as facility,
ISNULL(cast(cd.decision_date as varchar(20)), 'PENDING') as corporate,
ISNULL(cast(cb.creation_date as varchar(20)), 'PENDING') as billing
```

My values are originally of datetime datatype, but what I want to do is return the word 'PENDING' if the value is NULL.

With the code above, my results are `cast`ed to a `varchar`, thus returning something like:

```
Aug 20 2013 9:35AM
```

instead of `2013-08-20 09:35:54`

Suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `cast` with `convert` and appropriate *style*: [Convert syntax & styles](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/ms187928.aspx), eg:

```
ISNULL(convert(varchar(20), fd.decision_date, 120), 'PENDING') as facility,
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `cast(... as varchar(20))`, use `convert` with a style number, this is exactly what that's for.

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(19), GETDATE(), 120);
```

So your query becomes:

```
COALESCE(CONVERT(CHAR(19), fd.decision_date, 120), 'PENDING') as facility,
COALESCE(CONVERT(CHAR(19), cd.decision_date, 120), 'PENDING') as corporate,
COALESCE(CONVERT(CHAR(19), cb.creation_date, 120), 'PENDING') as billing
```