# Converting datetime to string 'pending' if null in a case statement

Tags: sql, datetime, type-conversion

I have a question while altering one of my columns in my view setup:

```
CASE 
   WHEN L.updateTime IS NULL 
      THEN ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), L.updateTime, 120), 'PENDING') 
      ELSE L.updateTime 
END AS updateTime
```

The command is successful, but when I try to select top 1000, it shows an error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

I've tried every options I can think of but nothing's working  Any suggestions?

Tried:

```
CASE 
   WHEN L.updateTime IS NULL 
      THEN 'PENDING' 
      ELSE L.updateTime 
END AS updateTime

CASE 
   WHEN L.updateTime IS NULL 
      THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), 'PENDING') 
      ELSE L.updateTime 
END AS updateTime

CASE 
   WHEN L.updateTime IS NULL 
      THEN ISNULL(L.updateTime, 'PENDING') 
      ELSE L.updateTime 
END AS updateTime
```

and many others...

I saw this existing question and tried it but, I still get error when I try to view my view.
[CASTing a datetime to string if null value - keeping original datetime formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18387612/casting-a-datetime-to-string-if-null-value-keeping-original-datetime-formattin)

Comment: `updateTime` is a `datetime` data type, and you want that the same `CASE` expression returns either a `varchar(20)` or a `datetime`...the same expression must return a single data type

Comment: You must cast the datatime to a string because *pending*  is not a valid timestamp. Try `COALESCE(CONVERT(varchar(20), L.updateTime, 120), 'PENDING')`

Comment: @dnoeth I just tried ```CASE WHEN L.updateTime IS NULL THEN COALESCE(CONVERT(varchar(20), L.updateTime, 120), 'PENDING') ELSE L.updateTime END AS updateTime``` but still the same error

Comment: You need only the `COALESCE` part :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out... I just needed to also convert the datetime in my else part of the statement as well.. to make sure in the case statement to all be in the same string format (since I'm converting to string)

Thanks @Lamak for the direction!

```
CASE WHEN L.updateTime IS NULL THEN ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(20), L.updateTime, 120),'PENDING') ELSE CONVERT(varchar(20), L.updateTime, 120) END AS updateTime
```

Answer (score 0):

The `CASE` expression returns *one* type.  By the typing rules of SQL, the most "restrictive" type is used.  That is, dates are returned over strings.  If the returned type is a date/time, then all strings -- including `'PENDING'` have to be converted.

And the `ELSE` clause means that the return type is a date/time.

I would recommend:

```
COALESCE(CONVERT(varchar(20), L.updateTime, 120), 'PENDING') AS updateTime
```

The `CASE` logic seems unnecessary.  `COALESCE()` does what you want.